# cv2.drawContours doesn't display all the contours

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image and I want to display all the contours using cv.drawContours but it misses one between two overlapped cells and I don't know why even though cv2.Canny shows clearly all the contours.
This is the code I used:

```
import cv2
import imageio
from skimage import io, color
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow


image = imageio.imread(path+'3.png')
print(image.shape)
image = color.gray2rgb(image)
print(image.shape)

cv2_imshow(image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find Canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# Finding Contours
# Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy()
# since findContours alters the image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(),
    cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2_imshow(edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))

# Draw all contours
# -1 signifies drawing all contours
img2=cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (100,0,0), 2)
print(len(contours))
print(img2.shape)
cv2_imshow(image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is the input image: [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9S40.png), this is the image after canny edging [edged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcXQm.png) and this is img2 the final image after cv2.drawCOntours [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf23D.png) and as you can see it misses the contour between the 2 overlapped cells in the middle. I will be grateful if you can help me solve this problem.

Comment: There is a gap in canny too. I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL to cv2.RETR_TREE

(also i suggest you to use less dependency)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('d:/python/X9S40.png')
cv2.imshow("",image)
# Grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Find Canny edges
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

# Finding Contours
# Use a copy of the image e.g. edged.copy()
# since findContours alters the image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(),
    cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.imshow("1",edged)

print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))

# Draw all contours
# -1 signifies drawing all contours
img2=cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
print(len(contours))
print(img2.shape)
cv2.imshow("2",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```